# Is this a valid dot product?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

So I have a homework problem, where
$$
F(x,y) = \sin(y) (4 x ~ \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j}) ~ \text{and} ~
\mathrm{d}{S} = - x ~ \mathbf{i} + y ~ \mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k},
$$
and I need to find the dot product of $ F(x,y) $ and $ \mathrm{d}{S} $, but I’m confused about how to do that when both the $ \mathbf{i} $ and $ \mathbf{j} $ components are inside of $ \sin $. I’ve written it exactly the same way it’s notated on my homework.

Comment: You say the i and j components stuff is in the sin...But I see see sin(y)(4xi+1j). Doesn't this mean sin(y) times (4xi+1j)?

Comment: The way it is written means $\sin y$ *times* that vector. And even if there is some abuse of notation in your classes sometimes, it is the only interpretation that makes sense.

Comment: You should read $\sin(y)(4x{bf i}+{bf j})$ as ${\bf i}\,4x\sin(y)+{\bf j}\,\sin(y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $F(x,y)=4x\ \mathrm{sin}(y)\ \mathbf{i}+ \mathrm{sin}(y)\mathbf{j}\ $ is a completely equivalent way of writing your function.